# Web safe colors that will work with Internet Explorer, Firefox, and Chrome. Background color is not working in IE within CSS

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-color, web-deployment

I am having this huge issue with IE 11, I can't get any variation of the color `royal blue` to display correctly as a background color. The background color works great in firefox and chrome.

I have tried all of this in the CSS file:

```
background-color:navy;

background-color:navy !important;

filter: none !important
```

I have tried other colors, like blue, and have tried to use just the color codes.

I have tried to force compatibility, If you run IE in compatibility, it will display the color correctly.  I can never seem to get IE 11 to run compatibility from `HTML`. I have tried the the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```

I am using the Doc Type tag as well:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

How it looks in Firefox:

[image: FireFox]

How it looks in IE 11:

[image: IE 11]

No matter what I do, I can't get internet explorer to display the background color that I want. Can someone please tell how I can accomplish this?

Comment: So does it not display anything or just the 'wrong' blue?

Comment: @Paulie_D It is the wrong blue

Comment: @Paulie_D Added the images to the question

Comment: Cannot reproduce....a link would be better. Also `RoyalBlue` is not the same as `Navy`

Comment: @nate Try reproducing it at a site like http://jsfiddle.net/. If you can, save it and post the link here so others can see.

Comment: have you tried entering the color as rgb or hex? `rgb(35,15,210)` or `#230fd2`?

Comment: @babpacih - this was my first thought as well.  I always use hex instead of the named colors - it seems to be more consistent across browsers.  I'm sure rgb would be the same way as well.

Comment: @babpacih I have tried other colors, like blue, and have tried to use just the HTML color codes and not the words.

Comment: @nate I cant replicate this issue. here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3fw9u4m/) i made for testing. Have you tried to replicate in a different context? like jsfiddle or a fresh .html doc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a really strange behavior, as color constants have been supported by IE for quite a while.  Your post contains a number of details, but not enough to help identify what might be going wrong in your case.

This [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rguh4uhr/1/) works correctly on my machine; that is, it changes the background color of the body element as requested.  Both `navy` and `royalblue` appear to work as intended on my copy of IE11.

Also, this [MSDN sample](http://samples.msdn.microsoft.com/workshop/samples/author/dhtml/colors/ColorTable.htm), written originally for IE8, continues to work in IE11 (though you need to use the F12 tools to switch the document mode.  BTW, that page also shows how to correctly declare the x-ua-compatible header to IE8 mode, if you're looking for such a live sample.)

To specify this (and the x-ua-compatible) directive in a bare bones HTML page, I might be tempted to use something like this:

```
<!doctype HTML>
<head>
  <title>My page title</title:>
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=8">
  <style type="text/css">
     body { background-color: navy }
  </style> 
</head>
<body>
   <p>Hello, world</p>
</body>
</html>
```

If your machine is not showing this, then I would consider other environmental factors, such as basic syntax errors, out of date video drivers, loose cable connections, or related things

Hope this helps...

-- Lance

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the wrong blue, it's most likely how IE is reading the color "Navy". Have you tried using specific HEX codes? A browser will read a hex code the same, but color names can appear differently, try using the HEX Code like below.

```
background:#000080; /*Navy BG Color*/
```

or

```
background-color:#000080; /*Navy BG Color*/
```

My IE displays these as the same colors.
Heres a site you can get the browser HEX codes for each color name:
http://www.color-hex.com/color/000080